# website responsive problem in desktop version

Tags: css, responsive-design

Actually I have been coding this Login form in html css but there is a problem in the responsive version in desktop, mobile responsive looks completely fine. Here the repository for this login form.

Here is the media queries for the desktop version -

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .login {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .login__content {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,max-content);
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 10rem;
  }

  .login__img {
    display: flex;
    width: 600px;
    height: 588px;
    background-color: var(--first-color-lighten);
    border-radius: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
  }

  .login__img img {
    width: 390px;
    margin-top: 0;
  }

  .login__register,
  .login__create {
    left: -11rem;
  }

  .login__register {
    bottom: -2rem;
  }

  .login__create {
    bottom: -5.5rem;
  }
}
```

Repo link - https://github.com/ARIF683/Login-Form.git

[Desktop version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrZNW.jpg)

[Mobile version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bh88X.jpg)

[Actual design I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYszM.jpg)

I will be glad if you help me

Comment: please include [mcve] in the question, not links to the code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your  `.login__create` class. In your media query use width of the `.login__create` class.